# ASP.NET gridview control rowCreated function after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering how can I control the execution order of server-side functions(asp.net and C#) for a post_back request?

For example: 
I have two buttons on my webpage, and click on any of them will trigger a post_back request. The post back will update a gridview in an AJAXUpdatePanel. I found that if I click button1, the functions execution order is:
button1_onclick();
gridview1_rowCreated();

However, if I click button 2, the order is:
gridview1_rowCreated();
button2_onClick();

Is there anyway to make the order consistent? Any comment is truly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code from your code behind?  I'm curious to see where/when you are databinding your gridview

Comment: Excellent point. button2_onclick() didn't have a databinding while button1_onclick() has. The order is consistent after I add a databinding in the button2_onclick() function. Thanks very much! I guess the reason is the row_created events got fired again after databinding, hence the order became consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Bind the grid on PreRender Event of the Page or Do the Task on the Button Clicked event and make sure you have first time binding done using an

```
if(!IsPostBack) 
{
 Code Binding Grid.
}
```